# Create div within another div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
  <div class="div1">
  </div>
```

I want to create a div inside div1 using javascript. Output will be like :

```
 <div class="div1">
      <div></div>
  </div>
```

How I can do it?

Comment: What's offtopic about this question? It seems very clear...

Comment: first learn basic from javascript and jQuery site

Comment: i do not understand how his could be off-topic!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".div1").html("<div></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery you can do:

`$("<div></div>").appendTo("div.div1")`